# GetStream - aggregated-feed time ordered

Tags: getstream-io

I have created a setup with GetStream, where i have some flat-feeds that contains data and an aggregated-feed that follows the flat-feeds.

I'm now uploading data to the flat-feeds from my database, with my own timestamp added to the activity. Which make my flat-feed ordered by time.

**Here is my problem:** When i'm following the flat-feeds with my aggregated-feed, the aggregated-feed seems to be sorted by last updated activity. Which i want to be sorted by my timestamp.

**My question:** Is i possible to sort the aggregated-feed by my own timestamp?

Comment: Found this link: https://getstream.io/blog/aggregated-feeds-demystified/
That says: _Aggregated feeds are sorted by the “updated_at” field of the aggregated activity. This allows you to bring a conversation back to the top of the feed._
**Can i somehow control this myself?**

Answer (score 1):

Stream aggregated feeds are sorted by the `updated_at` field of the aggregated activity.
At the moment there is no way to change this behaviour.

You can sort the activity groups on the client side before presenting the data to users.

Default aggregation format for aggregated feeds is `{{ verb }}_{{ time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}`
You can change your aggregation format to `{{ <name-of-your-custom-timestamp-field> }}` and sort aggregated feed content retrieval results on `group` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding.

My solution on this problem was to sort the lists, before i uploaded them to GetStream.

*But i still see a potential issue, if i have to upload "older" items later on...*

Comment: I have the exact same problem and this issue simply stopped me from pushing any older events to GetStream, as all older activities will be aggregated as "latest aggregated activities" then being pushed to the very top of the feed with this mechanism ...